# Display value on listitem of listview from Arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, textview, baseadapter

Two fragments,

- first fragment sends arraylist of product name and price to second fragment,
- Second fragment gets all values properly

**Question**

I want to display data on TextView. How can it possible?

Below is my code

**First Fragment**

```
alists=new ArrayList<String>();

     System.out.println("ARRAYLIST><><><><><"+alists);

            GenericUtility.setStringToSharedPrefsForKey("selected_prodname", user_name, getActivity());
            GenericUtility.setStringToSharedPrefsForKey("selected_prodprc", dollars+prod_price, getActivity());

            btn_add_to_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                       cartincrement();


                    productnams = GenericUtility.getStringFromSharedPrefsForKey("selected_prodname", getActivity());
                    System.out.println("Seleced user name=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=" + productnams);
                    productprc = GenericUtility.getStringFromSharedPrefsForKey("selected_prodprc", getActivity());
                    System.out.println("Seleced prodprice=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=" + productprc);

                    alists.add(productnams);
                    alists.add(productprc);

                }
            });


            relcart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Add_to_cart tf = new Add_to_cart();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                    bundle.putStringArrayList("prodnam", alists);
                   // bundle.putString("prodprce", productprc);
                    tf.setArguments(bundle);

                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, tf);
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                }
            });

        }
```

**Second Fragment**

```
public class Add_to_cart extends Fragment {

    private Button continue_shopping;
    private Button checkout;
    ListView list;
    private TextView _decrease,mBTIncrement,_value;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> alst;
    private String bname;

    public Add_to_cart(){}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_addtocart, container, false);

        alst=new ArrayList<String>();
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        alst = bundle.getStringArrayList("prodnam");

        System.out.println("NAM--"+alst);

       /* for(int i=0;i<alst.size();i++)
        {
             bname=alst.get(i);
        }*/

        continue_shopping=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_continueshoppping);
        checkout=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_chckout);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(),alst);
        list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_addtocart);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



       list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }
        });

        continue_shopping.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                HomeFragment tf = new HomeFragment();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, tf);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();

            }
        });

        checkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Checkout tf = new Checkout();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, tf);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<String> listData;
        //private AQuery aQuery;

        String dollars="\u0024";


        public CustomListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> listData) {
            this.context = context;
            this.listData=listData;
            // aQuery = new AQuery(this.context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_addtocart, null);
                holder.txtproname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.proname_addtocart);
                holder.txtprofilecast = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.proprice_addtocart);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

              holder.txtproname.setText(listData.get(position));

        holder.txtprofilecast.setText(dollars+listData.get(position));

            //holder.txtprofilecast.setText(dollars+listData.get(position));



            // aQuery.id(holder.propic).image(listData.get(position).get(TAG_IMAGE),true,true,0,R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            return convertView;
        }
        class ViewHolder{
            ImageView propic;
            TextView txtproname;
            TextView txtprofilecast;

        }
```

Comment: its already tried..and you can see that try in comment brother

Comment: so why did you comment it

Comment: because its not giving perfect output

Comment: in my listview i am getting 
holder.txtproname.setText(listData.get(position));
if i do something like this
its giving
listitem1-name
listitem2-price
listitem3-name1
listitem4-price1
what i want is
listitem1-name and price
listitem2-name1 and price1
now you got it

Comment: What output does it give? Is there a crash? Also, why do you pass context to constructor and don't use it later in getView?

Comment: no its not crash..see previous comment

Comment: I think the problem is you assignt same value to both textviews if listData.get(position) is "your text" it would display "your text" for txtproname and "$your text" for txtprofilecast

Comment: i want to get name and price in single listitem,,but i am getting individually..thats the issue..now you got it?

Comment: try creating two list and pass both.

Comment: then how will i set in text??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your list of items is actually twice as long as it should be. If you have 4 items in your list you will have 8 entries in your array (each item has 2 entries, a name and a price).

Instead of adding the name and price to a single array, you should create 2 parallel arrays. The first containing the list of names and the second containing the list of prices. Pass both arrays to the second fragment.

Comment: did that way but wht if i have different products..see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451589/how-to-set-values-after-using-mdoel-class-for-global-arraylist