# How to set values after using model class for global ArrayList?

Tags: android, arraylist, textview

I've created one model class to store my product name,price and quantity,and then I attach it to another `Fragment` and try to display it in my `TextView`. Unfortunately with that `ArrayList` I'm not able to get the position of the items. Following is my snippet code. I need help.

*Modelclass Arr_Model.Java*

```
public class Arr_Model {

    private String BRAND_NAME;
    private String BRNAD_PRICE;
    private String QTY ;

    public Arr_Model(){}

    public String getBRAND_NAME() {
        return BRAND_NAME;
    }

    public String getQTY() {
        return QTY;
    }

    public void setBRAND_NAME(String BRAND_NAME) {
        this.BRAND_NAME = BRAND_NAME;
    }

    public void setBRNAD_PRICE(String BRNAD_PRICE) {
        this.BRNAD_PRICE = BRNAD_PRICE;
    }

    public void setQTY(String QTY) {
        this.QTY = QTY;
    }

    public String getBRNAD_PRICE() {
        return BRNAD_PRICE;
    }
}
```

Here I am getting the values from response and store them in `arraylist`

*ProductDetail.java*

1)First i am getting data from response,it is product name and its price

class LoadAlbums extends AsyncTask>> {
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(All_Product_Details.this.getActivity());
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}
protected ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... args) {

    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(USER_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);
    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {


                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONObject pname = jsonObj.getJSONObject(PRODUCT_MAIN);
                System.out.println("Jsonobject product>>" + pname);
                JSONArray sizes = new JSONArray();
                sizes = pname.getJSONArray("attributes");
                for (int j = 0; j < sizes.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject jsonnewtwo = sizes.getJSONObject(j);
                    option = jsonnewtwo.getJSONArray("options");
                    System.out.println("Option---" + option);

                }
                System.out.println("Attribute size" + sizes);
                user_name = pname.getString(USER_NAME);
                prod_price = pname.getString(PRODUCT_PRICE);
                prod_desc = pname.getString(PRODUCT_DESC);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
    if(user_name.equals(""))
    {
        uname.setText("Not Available");
    }
    else
    {
        uname.setText(user_name);
    }

    if(prod_price.equals(""))
    {
        pprice.setText("Not Available");
    }
    else
    {
        pprice.setText(dollars+prod_price);
    }

    if(prod_desc.equals(""))
    {
        general_desc.setText("Not Available");
    }
    else
    {
        general_desc.setText(Html.fromHtml(prod_desc).toString());
    }
```

2)then i increase product quantity and click on add to cart button,on click of add to cart i am saving data in arraylist..

```
 btn_add_to_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    cartincrement();
                    productnams = GenericUtility.getStringFromSharedPrefsForKey("selected_prodname", getActivity());
                    //System.out.println("Seleced user name=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=" + productnams);
                    productprc = GenericUtility.getStringFromSharedPrefsForKey("selected_prodprc", getActivity());
                    //System.out.println("Seleced prodprice=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=" + productprc);
                    Arr_Model product = new Arr_Model();
                    product.setBRAND_NAME(user_name);
                    product.setBRNAD_PRICE(prod_price);
                    product.setQTY(_value.getText().toString());
                    productArraylist.add(product);

                    System.out.println("TEst--" + productArraylist.get(0).getBRAND_NAME());
                }
            });
            //System.out.println("Test--" + productArraylist.get(0).getBRAND_NAME());

            mBTIncrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    increment();

                }
            });

            _decrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    decrement();
                }
            });
```

3)then i click on cart icon to view which item i added with its quantity

```
relcart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        _value.setText("1");
                        Add_to_cart tf = new Add_to_cart();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, tf);
                        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                        ft.addToBackStack(null);
                        ft.commit();
                    }
                });

            }
```

4)now final step to display items in listview,to next fragment

```
public class Add_to_cart extends Fragment {

    private Button continue_shopping;
    private Button checkout;
    ListView list;
    private TextView _decrease,mBTIncrement,_value;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> alst;
    private ArrayList<String> alstprc;
    private String bname;
    private ArrayList<Arr_Model> productArraylist;


    public Add_to_cart(){}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_addtocart, container, false);

       productArraylist = All_Product_Details.productArraylist;
        // alst=new ArrayList<String>();
       // Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
       // alst = bundle.getStringArrayList("prodnam");
        //consts.arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        //consts.arr = alst;
       // System.out.println("NAM--" + productArraylist);

       // Bundle bundle1 = this.getArguments();
       // alstprc = bundle1.getStringArrayList("prodprc");




/*
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(),alst);
        list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_addtocart);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {


            }
        });*/


        return rootView;
    }

    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<Arr_Model> listData;
        //private AQuery aQuery;

        String dollars="\u0024";


        public CustomListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Arr_Model> listData) {
            this.context = context;
            this.listData=listData;
            // aQuery = new AQuery(this.context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_addtocart, null);
                holder.txtproname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.proname_addtocart);
                holder.txtprofilecast = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.proprice_addtocart);

                _decrease = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.minuss_addtocart);
                mBTIncrement = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus_addtocart);
                _value = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_procount_addtocart);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            mBTIncrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    increment();
                }
            });

            _decrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    decrement();
                }
            });

           /* for(int i=0;i<productArraylist.size();i++)
            {
                holder.txtproname.setText(productArraylist.get(0));
            }

            holder.txtprofilecast.setText(dollars+alstprc.get(position));*/
            // aQuery.id(holder.propic).image(listData.get(position).get(TAG_IMAGE),true,true,0,R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            return convertView;
        }
        class ViewHolder{
            ImageView propic;
            TextView txtproname;
            TextView txtprofilecast;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
relcart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        _value.setText("1");
        Add_to_cart tf = new Add_to_cart();

        tf.setList(productArraylist);

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, tf);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
});
```

Add below method in Fragment.

```
public void setList(ArrayList<Arr_Model> p_productArraylist) {
       productArraylist = p_productArraylist;
}
```

Comment: but first i want to check that..in addtocart click listener whatever i am adding is working or not..so how to check that

Comment: I am not able to access setList method for my arraylist..its not working

Answer (score 0):

First create an application class like this,

public class Applicationc extends Application{

```
public String str;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    str=null;
}
```

}

create its entry like this in manifest

then in onPost of Async Task set the value in following way,

Applicationc app=(Applicationc)getApplicatoncotext();
app.str="data";

And where you want to retrieve value in following way,

Applicationc app=(Applicationc)getApplicatoncotext();
String dd=app.str;

Comment: This is overkill. You don't need to extend the `Application` class to do this. You can just use 'public static' variables in any class. Also, you forgot to tell OP to add this custom `Application` class to his manifest. If he doesn't do this, it won't work anyway.

Comment: if you declare it in application class, then it will be availabe trhoughout the app...

Comment: If you declare anything as 'public static' it will be available throughout the app.

Comment: @DavidWasser, if due to any reason, if that activity gets killed, then that static variable will not lose all its value, that's i declare it in application class

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work like that. Even if an Activity gets killed, the static variable will retain its state. This is how class variables work in Java. When the classloader loads the class, it allocates space for the static variables and initializes them. This happens even if an instance of the class (an object) is never created. And even if all objects of that class are reclaimed by the garbage collector, the class itself is not unloaded. The static variables in any class will stay around (and retain their values) until the VM exits (ie: until the process is killed).

Comment: You don't need to put the static variable in an `Activity`, You can put it in **any class**. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11373779/769265 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really follow all this code. If I understand you correctly, you are having a problem passing the data around between your `Activity`, `AsyncTask` and `Fragment`s. A good architecture here would be to have the `Activity` keep track of the data. The `Fragment` can always ask the `Activity` for the data and the `AsyncTask` can also call back to the `Activity` to update the data.

If this isn't enough information to solve your problem, please show exactly the place where you are having trouble.